# Unit test file setup for Angular JS

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs, jasmine

I am writing my first unit tests for an Angular JS project, and I'm wondering how to lay thing out in a easy to understand and maintain manner.

For directives for example the examples I have found so far usually have one file for directives, with in it one describe(). In my opinion that would easily become quite a big file to maintain.

I think it makes more sense to have a file per directive, and then in that directive have a describe for the directive itself,like this for a myDate directive, with filename "myDateDirectiveSpec.js". That already makes things easier to read, but then I'm still a bit concerned about directives with a lot of functions. In the example below I add comments to indicate where I test which function, but isn't there a better way?

```
describe("myDate", function() {
  var $compile, $rootScope;
  var validDate, invalidDate, invalidDateFormat;

  beforeEach(angular.mock.module('main'));

  beforeEach(inject(
      ['$compile','$rootScope', function($c, $r) {
          $compile = $c;
          $rootScope = $r;
      }]
  ));

  // test function validDate
  it("should check if the given date is a valid date", function() {
      validDate = '31-8-2011';
      expect(isValidDate(validDate)).toBe(true);
  })

  // test function formatDate
  it("format the given date", function() {
      validDate = '31-8-2011';
      expect(formatDate(validDate)).toBe('31/8/2011');
  })

  // test function anotherFunction
  it("....", function() {
      validDate = '31-8-2011';
      expect(anotherFunction(validDate)).toBe(true);
  })

  // test function anotherFunction
  it("....", function() {
      validDate = '31-8-2011';
      expect(anotherFunction(validDate)).toBe(true);
  })

  // test function anotherFunction
  it("....", function() {
      validDate = '31-8-2011';
      expect(anotherFunction(validDate)).toBe(true);
  })


});
```

If a directive has a lot of functions in it can I somehow split them out in a smarter way then what I did in the above example?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure this would apply to testing a directive as I have yet to do so myself. However; When testing services and controllers, what I will usually do is start nesting describe blocks.

I'm not too familiar with Jasmine, or any potential performance issues this may cause (it's something I'm planning on checking out), but if anyone has something to share on that please do.

So what I'm doing is something like this:

```
describe("myDate", function() {
  var $compile, $rootScope;
  var validDate, invalidDate, invalidDateFormat;

  beforeEach(angular.mock.module('main')); 

  beforeEach(inject(
    ['$compile','$rootScope', function($c, $r) {
        $compile = $c;
        $rootScope = $r;
    }]

  describe("validDate", function () {
    it("should check if the given date is a valid date", function() {
      validDate = '31-8-2011';
      expect(isValidDate(validDate)).toBe(true);
    });        
  });

  describe("someOtherFunction, function () {
    it("does something", function () {
     // do something here
    });

    it("does something else", function () {
     // do something else here
    });
  });

));
```

Like you, I prefer splitting up my spec files on a per file basis (I don't have a 'directives.js' file with all of my directives in em, they are all separated). I prefer keeping my spec folder just about the same way as my application files, makes it easier for me to stay organized.

I personally think (again, personal preference) that this way of nesting describe blocks makes it easier on the eyes when writing and reading tests. If it does in fact have any performance issues however, one might switch over to one describe block - and a lot of it("")'s.